# Порядок выполнения операторов sql запроса

Tags: sql

Пожалуйста, дайте порядок выполнения операторов sql запроса или дайте ссылку, где прочитать об этом: что за чем выполняется. Например (с потолка):

```sql
SELECT
  t1.id AS id, t1.name AS name, count(*) AS cnt
FROM
  tbl_name1 t1
INNER JOIN
  tbl_name2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
  t1.id > 10
GROUP BY
  t1.name
HAVING
  cnt > 10
ORDER BY
  t1.id
```

Сначала `GROUP BY`, потом? Последним `ORDER BY`... 
Нигде не могу найти нормальной информации об этом :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Порядок выполнения предложений в операторе select](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_having_clause.html)

Comment: а вот про JOIN там ни слова! :) или оно к  FROM приравнивается? если так - то перед FROM или после? :)

Comment: а, наверное внутренний оптимизатор сводит все к предложению WHERE? как думаете, коллеги?

Comment: Соединение таблиц (JOIN) находится в предложении FROM и только там.

Comment: т.е. JOIN не отдельный оператор, а как часть предложения FROM?

Comment: Да. Во FROM перечисляются таблицы, используемые в запросе. Начиная со стандарта SQL-92, там могут использоваться явные операции их соединения (т.е. JOIN). До этого условия соединения задавались в предложении WHERE.

Answer (score 9):

Для SQL Server смотри [ссылку](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189499%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

Логический порядок обработки инструкции SELECT:

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. where
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE или WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

Answer (score 2):

Порядок выполнения зависит от ситуации и определяется перед выполнением запроса. СУБД позволяют просмотреть план выполнения - это то, как именно СУБД решила выполнить запрос.

Comment: вопрос не про порядок выполнение запроса, а про порядок выполнения операторов - он фиксированный

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
       [DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW | ALL]
       select_expression,...
   [FROM table_references]
     [WHERE where_definition]
     [GROUP BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | formula} [ASC | DESC], ...]
     [HAVING where_definition]
     [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | formula} [ASC | DESC], ...]
```

Comment: Это синтаксис, а порядок разбора отличается от синтаксического порядка, например, предложение select выполняется почти в самом конце, перед order by. Именно поэтому алиасы, данные столбцам, не видны, скажем, в предложении where.